# Is it permissible to work at a tzaar-baalei-chayyim store?

Tags: tzaar-baalei-chayyim, employment

Are you allowed to work at a store (pet shop, for example) that does tzaar-baalei-chayyim to the animals it has there?

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: Would one be permitted to work at Red Lobster - or a French restaurant that serves frogs' legs or a restaurant that serves clams - knowing that the way that a lobster is killed is by tossing it into a pot of boiling water so it doesn't emit a gas that it naturally emits when killed otherwise, or frogs by slowly boiling them so they don't feel the heat and jump out, or that clams are eaten while still alive?

Answer (score 3):

If this is a Jewish-owned store, and working for them facilitates the sin, it is probably prohibited to work there.

BUT You should find out if the Tza'ar being committed in the store is in fact halachically impermissible. There are many valid situations where the tza'ar is permitted.

If this is a non-Jewish store, I don't know of a source that prohibits tza'ar balei chaim to non-Jews, so there's no Lifnei Iver. Of course, if the behavior is illegal according to American law, that would be entirely different.

Comment: If it was Ever Min HaChai it would be a problem for non-jews too.